# if statement with dates js

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have this:

```js
let currentTime = new Date(customerid)
currentTime = currentTime.setDate(currentTime.getDate());
customerid = new Date(customerid)
currentTime = new Date(currentTime)

console.log(customerid)
console.log(currentTime)

if (customerid == currentTime) {
  res.redirect('/create-checkout-session')
} else {
  console.log("having to go into loading screen")
  res.redirect("/loadingscreen")
}
```

When i log what is happening:

```
 console.log(customerid)
 console.log(currentTime)
```

It returns this:

```
2022-02-13T00:00:00.000Z
2022-02-13T00:00:00.000Z
```

whcih I thought was fine, however, I then do the if statement logic, and it doesn't work, it goes into the else.

so when I do:

```
if (customerid == currentTime) {
```

it says it is not the same, although the output above shows that it is. Am i not able to do if logic with date paramaters? How should i fix this?

Comment: Use `customerid.valueOf() === currentTime.valueOf()`

Comment: @Phil sweet, thank you!